# Issue with Match Against in search query

Tags: php, mysql, match, fulltext-index

I have a situation with a website who lists products.

I'm using a fulltext index with a Match Against search

There is a field named "itemcode" that field is in varchar type

turns out one of the codes for instance, goes like

> "WTC-153-U"

And when i type on the textbox **"WTC-153"** i get no results, i guess it's based on the hyphen and numbers, is there any workaround or a better method for this?

I cannot seem to find a solution at the moment without having to modify that much code

The query goes like this

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE MATCH(itemcode) AGAINST ('WTC-153')
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your query look like? I hope you are using `where itemcode like 'WTC-153%'`?

Comment: `Like` didn't ever worked for me, since when they were mixed words no matches were found, im using match against

Comment: @TJ- the whole point of MySQL FULLTEXT is to avoid expensive `LIKE` queries.

Answer (score 0):

`-` counts as a word separator, so `'WTC-153-U'` counts as three words, `'WTC'`, `'153'` and `'U'`.

With MyISAM, the default lower word length limit for full text searches is four characters and with InnoDB it is 3 (these can be changed).

If you are using InnoDB, you could get around the issue by searching for both `'WTC'` and `'153'` in the text.. obviously, this will return a result even if these words are not together or in the right order.

Otherwise you could search with `LIKE '%WTC-153%'` but that wouldn't be able to use the index. `LIKE 'WTC-153%'` will be able to use the index, but will only return the row if the field starts with `'WTC-153'`.

Comment: Hi, i'm using MyISAM, the MySQL version won't allow fullindex with InnoDB, how can i change the length? and what work around can i use which doesn't affect the current code so much, since it based on a bunch of dynamic filters and joins

Comment: @DannyG I'd use `LIKE '%WTC-153-U%'`, it is the only thing guaranteed to return the correct results. On further inspection it is very strange to have a full text index on an itemcode.

Comment: i tought about that, but what if there is an item named "Black stripped keyboard" and the user types "black keyboard"?

Comment: You should really separate out your itemcode search logic from your item name search logic.. `LIKE` is case insensitive however.